# Why can't I see my Google Cloud Container Registry images?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-container-registry

When I navigate to https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/ my list appears to be empty (see the attached screenshot), even though I am successfully using a couple of Firebase Functions. Is the link broken? Am I missing permissions or something? Where are my images? Why can't I access them?

[image]

Comment: Did you push containers to container registry? If not, and even if when you deploy a Firebase function (or a Cloud Functions) a container is created, these  specials google made containers aren't visible here. Don't expect to view them.

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically build and push images to a private registry when you commit code to Cloud Source Repositories, GitHub, or Bitbucket. Easily set up CI/CD pipelines with integration to Cloud Build or deploy directly to Google Kubernetes Engine, App Engine, Cloud Functions, or Firebase.

Pushing an image for the first time to the registry in your project you need **Storage Admin** (roles/storage.admin) at the [Google Cloud project level](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#project-iam). But if you are
pushing an image to an existing registry in your project then you need **Role: Storage Legacy Bucket Writer** (roles/storage.objectAdmin) on the registry storage
bucket.

For more details [pushing and pulling images](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling).

Also please check [managing images](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing).